# Trying to style labels of focused inputs on dynamic forms

Tags: jquery, css, forms, label

> **Solved:** Seems my issue was caused by CSS inheritance. For the record, the second snippet in my original question actually worked.

I have html forms with inputs and labels.

When I focus an input, I can successfully change the label style using jquery. This is done using the snippet below:

```
$("input, textarea").focus(function(){
  $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("labelfocus");
})
.blur(function()
{
  $("label").removeClass("labelfocus");
});
```

However, this does not work with dynamically generated forms.

I've tried using jquery's "$(document).on(…" but that's not doing it for me either. See snippet below:

```
$(document).on({
    focus: function() {
        $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("labelfocus");
    },
    blur: function() {
        $("label").removeClass("labelfocus");
    }
}, "input, textarea");
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Oops. Seems my issue was caused by CSS inheritance. For the record, the second snippet in my original question actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a cleaner way, but I would try it like this

```
$('input, textarea').on('focus', function() {
$("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("labelfocus");
});

$('input, textarea').on('blur', function() {
$("label").removeClass("labelfocus");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(document).on` if you use `$("input, textarea").on` I think it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I believe that an ancestor element must be specified where `$(document)` currently is. I also tried using the id of the containing element that gets dynamically generated, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this or anything but wouldn't you want to further specify the blur event to use the full $("label[for='" + this.id + "']") as well?

My mind is telling me that if you are focused on an input and mouse-click or tab directly to another input then there would be conflicting focus/blur operations occurring.

Comment: I'm not having any conflicting focus/blur issues. But your suggestion is most definitely a good one. At the least it would be less work to blur one specific label as opposed to blurring every one.